# Jenkins active choice React reference parameter Groovy script to get array content from file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

[image: Parameter Code Block]

I'm trying to display list for rollback parameter in Jenkins from a file (where file has roll back numbers in each line) I'm reading that content and storing it as array and returned this array in the code block but parameter has no drop-down values.

I'm not getting any error - Not sure what am I doing wrong here.

```
if(ENV == "INT") {
def filePath = "C:\\\\Users\\\\Lenovo\\\\OneDrive\\\\Documents\\\\Jenkins-Test\\\\test.txt"
                def fileContent = readFile file: filePath
                def modifiedList = fileContent.readLines()
               def values = modifiedList.collect { "\"${it}\"" }.join(',')
                return values
}
else if(ENV == "VAL") {
return ["Test", "Hello"]
}
else {
return ["1", "2"]
}
```

ENV is the previous parameter I'm using it as referenced parameter here.

[image: Param UI]

Can anyone please suggest solution for this !

I'm expecting below:

Test.txt (File content is not static and each value will be in new line) has file content:

```
R1v112
R1v122
R1v123
```

I want to display if ENV selected is INT then rollback drop-down should display values R1v112,
R1v122,
R1v123 for selection.

Comment: Can't you just return `modifiedList`?

Comment: @cfrick Tried that too- But It is jumping into Fallback Script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not writing a scripted pipeline here, it's a pure Groovy script, so Jenkins steps like `readFile` are not defined. Error reporting for Active Choices sucks, you have to resort to hacks like this to see what actually failed

```
try {
... your code
} catch(e) {
    return [e.toString()]
}
```

In your case the Groovy code could be

```
if(ENV == "INT") {
    return new File("C:\\\\Users\\\\Lenovo\\\\OneDrive\\\\Documents\\\\Jenkins-Test\\\\test.txt").readLines()
}
```

Comment: How do we read the file which is in server as it says file not found everytime even if the file exists ! Please answer

Comment: This code runs on the same server as Jenkins, not on any agent. Try listing files if you are not sure what the file system looks like from Jenkins perspective.